# Is it possible to extend build.sbt syntax using implicit classes?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a big root sbt project that contains several sub-projects. Among those project definitions there is a lot of code duplication that I am trying to remove.

For example every assembly project contains the following code:

```
project
  .enablePlugins(sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin)
  .settings(
    mainClass in Compile := Some(mainClassName),
    assemblyJarName in assembly := jarName,
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case PathList("sandbox.sc") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case PathList("org", "joda", "time", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
      case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
      case x => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    }
  )
```

Instead i would like to write something like that:

```
project
  .assembly(className, jarName)
```

Is it possible to achieve such syntax? I know it is possible to achieve this syntax in a typical scala file using an implicit class. Is these a way to do it in sbt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. create `object`(`SbtProjectImplicits.scala`) under the `project` directory(depend on your project structure), like:

```
your-project/
   project/SbtProjectImplicits.scala
   src/
   ...
```

and the `SbtProjectImplicits.scala` object content maybe like:

```
object SbtProjectImplicits {
    implicit class ProjectSettings(p: sbt.Project) {
      def assembly(className: Class, jarName): sbt.Project = {
        p.settings(
         mainClass in Compile := Some(mainClassName),
         assemblyJarName in assembly := jarName,
         ...
        )
        p
      }
    }
}
```

so you can in `build.sbt` do it like:

```
import SbtProjectImplicits._
project
  .assembly(className, jarName)
```

Comment: Thank you @chengpohi, it works like a breeze and helped me to better understand sbt.